# How would I draw a signal flow diagram for the transfer function of a resonant filter?

Tags: filter, transfer-function, dsp, digital-filter

The transfer function is:

$$H(z)=\frac{(1-r)(1-rz^{-2})}{1-2r\cos(\omega T)z^{-1} + r^2z^{-2}}$$

I have started by finding the difference equation, but I don't know how to draw a signal flow diagram for this.

The difference equation I have got for this filter, by setting $$H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$$

Is: $$y(n) = 2rcos(wT)y(n-1) - r^2y(n-2) + x(n) -rx(n-2) + r^2x(n-2) - rx(n)$$

Now, what I am looking to do is draw a signal flow diagram for this filter.

Comment: You say "flow chart" in one place and "flow diagram" in another.  Please _edit your question_ to clarify what you mean.  While you're typing, say what you're trying to _do_ -- the most likely thing I can think of is that you want to write code that implements the filter, but I don't have enough information.  Note that if that _is_ what you want to do, I'll probably dis-recommend a flow chart, so if this is homework and it's required _say that, too_, but then show us what work you've done to implement this on your own.

Comment: Do you mean block diagram?

Comment: Thanks @TimWescott I've updated the question a bit with what I have so far. I am not looking to write code to implement this filter, rather I am just looking to draw out the signal flow diagram - That is, a visual representation of the filter itself

Comment: Hi @imthegman55, The questions states a signal flow diagram however I think this is the same thing as a block diagram?

Comment: @Ben120 You'll probably want to read about [direct form I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_I) and [direct form II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_II), transposed or not.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen this is exactly what I'm trying to create thank you! I'm a little confused on how I create this for the difference equation stated above, I'm not even sure where to start with it

Comment: @Ben120 If I were you I'd be careful about asking to be spoonfed on this site. To alleviate that, I'd first try to do it myself and, only if I don't make it I'll consider asking, while showing my attempts, as well. It's much easier to point out the errors in what you're showing than to try to guess what you could have gotten wrong, wouldn't you agree? Plus, that way people will not think that you're trying to make them solve your problems in your stead -- which I'm sure is not the case.